# Download single Object of Firestore and save it into an struct/class object

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

I am coding since January 2019 and this is my first post here.

I am using Swift and Firestore. In my App is a tableView where I display events loaded out of a single Document with an array of events inside as [String: [String:Any]]. If the user wants to get more infos about an event he taps on it. In the background the TableViewController will open a new "DetailEventViewController" with a segue and give it the value of the eventID in the tapped cell.

When the user is on the DetailViewController Screen the app will download a new Document with the EventID as key for the document.

I wanna save this Data out of Firestore in a Struct called Event. For this example just with Event(eventName: String).

When I get all the data I can print it directly out but I can't save it in a variable and print it out later. I really don't know why. If I print the struct INSIDE the brackets where I get the data its working but if I save it into a variable and try to use this variable it says its nil.

So how can I fetch data out of Firestore and save in just a Single ValueObject (var currentEvent = Event? -> currentEvent = Event.event(for: data as [String:Any]) )

I search in google, firebaseDoc and stackoverflow but didn't find anything about it so I tried to save all the singe infos of the data inside a singe value.

```
// Struct

struct Event {
var eventName: String!

static func event(for eventData: [String:Any]) -> Event? {
guard let _eventName = eventData["eventName"] as? String    
else {
print("error")
return nil
}
return Event(eventName: _eventName)
}
```

// TableView VC *this should work*

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "ShowEventDetailSegue" {
  if let ShowEvent = segue.destination as?                                               DetailEventViewController, let event = eventForSegue{
            ShowEvent.currentEventId = event.eventID
        }
    }
}
```

// DetailViewController

```
var currentEvent = Event()
var currentEventId: String?

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    guard let _eventID = currentEventId else {
        print("error in EventID")
        return}

    setupEvent(eventID: _eventID) /* currentEvent should be set here                 */
    setupView(event: currentEvent) /* currentEvent has after     "setupEvent" the value of nil */
}

func setupEvent(eventID: String) {

let FirestoreRef =     Firestore.firestore().collection("events").document(eventID)

FirestoreRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
        if let err = error {
            debugPrint("Error fetching docs: \(err)")
            SVProgressHUD.showError(withStatus: "Error in Download")
        }else {
            if let document = document, document.exists {
                guard let data = document.data() else {return}

            let eventData = Event.event(for: data as [String:Any])

                print(eventData)
//here all infos are printed out - so I get them

                self.currentEvent = eventData! 

//Here is the error.. I can't save the fetched Data in my single     current Event 
} else {
                SVProgressHUD.showError(withStatus: "Error")
            }
        }
    }


}

func setupView(event: Event) {
self.titleLabel.text = event.eventName
}
```

I expect that the function setupEvents will give the currentEvent in the DetailViewController a SINGLEvalue cause its a SINGLE document not an array. So I can use this single Eventvalue for further actions. Like starting a new segue for a new ViewController and just push the Event there not

Comment: Try calling the second async method inside the first one’s closure instead of setting the current event value

Comment: Okay now I can display all my of UIElements correctly. But I still have the problem that the info is not saved in the struct so i cant use this for more actions like loading the galary or  show location of an event in another ViewController.

Comment: What do you mean? You have the current value there as well

Comment: you mean i should add the "setupView(event: Event)" directly after "self.currentEvent = eventData!" right? 

Now I the eventName displays on the textLabel but if I want to use it for another action out of the Firebase method like:  

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
   
    setupEvent(eventID: _eventID) /* currentEvent should be set here in currentEvent? */
    print(currentEvent.eventName) // Will result as nil
}